# Save Eigen array row in a variable

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I'm trying to extract the `j`-th row from an `Eigen::ArrayXXi` and store it in a variable. This is what I tried.

```
Eigen::Array<int, arr.rows(), arr.cols()> row = arr.row(j);
```

But I get the following error highlighting `arr.rows()`

> Non-type template argument of type 'Eigen::Index' (aka 'long') is not an integral constant expression

I am unable to find what the return type of `arr.row()` is supposed to be. According to the documentation, it's `RowExpr`, which means nothing to me.

Comment: rows() is not a constant expression, you cannot use it in a template https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/structEigen_1_1EigenBase.html#ab75c2d8a783d055db397319c5a330eee . Do you know what size the array should be? If yes, try hardcoding the values in the template.

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. No, I don't know what size it should be at compile time.

Comment: Try Eigen::Array<int, Dynamic, Dynamic> that's what the docs tell me you should use when you don't know the sizes at compile time. https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html . If it doesn't work we need more code (a minimum reproducible example) to copy/paste in a compiler and look at the issue better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use

```
Eigen::Array<int, arr.rows(), arr.cols()> row = arr.row(j);
```

Because `rows()` and `cols()` aren't `constexpr`, hence they are not a const expression as written in the error message: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/structEigen_1_1EigenBase.html#ab75c2d8a783d055db397319c5a330eee .

You have two choices, if the sizes are known at compile time, hard-code the values, otherwise, as explained in this tutorial https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html use:

```
Eigen::Array<int, Dynamic, Dynamic> row = arr.row(j);
```

to have dynamic sizes. Fore more information on using Dynamic sizes refer to the documentation of `Matrix` which is referenced to from the docs of `Array`: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html

I can see that `Eigen::Array<int, Dynamic, Dynamic>` has as alias `ArrayXXi`: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__arraytypedefs.html#gab2c3a894f02fb9fdbc3de996c9d02312

**Edit** as pointed out by user ggael one can also use `ArrayXi` given that we know at least one dimension, which is 1.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a copy of it, then you can assign it within a 1D array:

```
ArrayXi arr_j = arr.row(j);
```

If you want to preserve the fact that a row is `1xN`, then:

```
Array<int,1,Dynamic> arr_j = arr.row(j);
```

or (equivalently):

```
auto arr_j = arr.row(j).eval();
```

Finally, if you want a reference to the original data, then:

```
auto arr_j = arr.row(j);
```

or (equivalently):

```
ArrayXXi::RowExpr arr_j = arr.row(j);
```